# count all results from a db query active records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('myTable')->where('name',$user_name)->get()->results_array();
```

If i do this after the query above,

```
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Even though myTable has rows :

> Table: myTable Column1 name: id Column2 name: name
>
> row1 - 1 row1 - peter row2 - 2 row2 - peter

It would echo 1, although there are 2 peters. My thoughts is that i returned the results as an array.

How should i return the results? Active_records class does not show how to. It only shows another format where i type in the query myself manually. I don't like doing queries like that.

Although might i ask for professionals' opinion. Which is better. The way im doing it or the examples in active records like,

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Although they dont show an example where you specifically select column names.

Comment: Ive tried the get_where query and still the same. Would only pick up 1 instead of 2.

Comment: you should use `num_rows()`  i.e `$query->num_rows()` ?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already solved it myself.

Since i was passing query results, after i stored it in an assoc array with id as its $key then the value as array($values(name,etc.)).

After which, the name of that assoc array assume its $array. i just used. count($array);

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in 2 steps.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('myTable')->where('name',$user_name)->get();

$result = $query->result_array();

$countResult = $query->num_rows();
```